# how to call java that takes array of strings from jruby

Tags: java, jruby

I've got this method in java:

`static void runCommand(String[] commands) ...`

When I attempt to call it from Jruby I get:

```
>> YYY.runCommand(["a", "b", "c"])

NameError (no method 'runCommand' for arguments (org.jruby.RubyArray) on Java::XXX::YYY)
  available overloads:
     ...
    (java.lang.String[])
```

How do I call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears you have to convert the array manually.  Bummer.

`runCommand(["a", "b"].to_java(:string)]`

And it works.